# How to trigger when abap screen listbox was selected a value

Tags: triggers, listbox, screen, abap, dynpro

I have to catch when a list box is selected in a screen to update a field value.
Is there any way to catch the change?

Comment: The "way to catch the change" is to compare the value displayed and the value after it has been changed (dynpro fields are global variables, so have two global variables). I don't get what is your issue, please clarify your question.

Comment: Check in PBO if it's selected

Comment: Thanks! It was simple. Just used  the variables and the field and I compared them.